# Unable to connect to vncserver

Tags: linux, vnc, remote-desktop

Just trying to figure out the problem with vncserver here. It looks like it is only listening to local host and hence keeps giving this message `No matching security types` when I try to access this linux machine from another computer. Any suggestions?

```
 owner@owner1:~$ vncserver -list

TigerVNC server sessions:

X DISPLAY # PROCESS ID
:1      9210
:10     1711
:11     24220
:12     27984
:13     4959
:14     5569
:15     25111
:16     25754
:17     32615
:18     21558
:2      9797
:3      10726
:4      11376
:5      12890
:6      13563
:7      15550
:8      19001
:9      19659
```

Also,

```
`ss -l`
owner@owner1:~$ ss -l
Netid  State    Recv-Q   Send-Q                                   Local Address:Port                                            Peer Address:Port               
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/9751                                        *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/9657                                        *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/9684                                        *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/11902                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/31851                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/28202                                            *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/3829                                        *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/3583                                             *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/11567                                            *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:-1442839630                                                 *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:whoopsie/3390                                               *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/25585                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/14952                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/10383                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/10247                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/11151                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/9473                                             *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/19390                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/15951                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/24651                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/11304                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:gnome-software/3721                                         *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:firefox/9139                                                *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/13088                                            *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/5997                                        *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/24619                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/11785                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/10040                                            *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/21462                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/13293                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/3785                                        *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:gnome-software/11110                                        *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/28409                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/6040                                        *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/13955                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/11178                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/17487                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/13980                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/25360                                            *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/10133                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/10220                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/5179                                             *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/5816                                             *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:kernel                                                      *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/14431                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/26929                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/5402                                        *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/15764                                            *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/24432                                            *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/11758                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/13268                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/25619                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:systemd-resolve/698                                         *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:packagekitd/25547                                           *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/19205                                            *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/15978                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/13769                                            *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:avahi-daemon/4671                                           *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:gnome-software/10178                                        *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/10969                                            *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:gnome-software/9612                                         *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/5430                                        *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/28445                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/19426                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/6020                                        *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/10265                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/25619                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/25585                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/25360                                            *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:firefox/9139                                                *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:packagekitd/25547                                           *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:avahi-daemon/4671                                           *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/10133                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/9751                                        *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/6040                                        *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/5997                                        *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/5816                                             *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/5430                                        *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/5402                                        *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/5179                                             *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/31851                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/28445                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/28409                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/28202                                            *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/26929                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/24651                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/24619                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/24432                                            *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/21462                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/19426                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/19390                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/19205                                            *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/17487                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/15978                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/15951                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/15764                                            *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/14952                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/14431                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/13980                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/13955                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/13769                                            *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/13293                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/13268                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:goa-daemon/13088                                            *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:deja-dup-monito/11902                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-addre/11785                                       *                   
nl     UNCONN   0        0                                                 rtnl:evolution-calen/11758                                       *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is this bug in Ubuntu and can be fixed by :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```